# How to show only failed test in sbt test?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have tried command 'sbt "project camera-answer" test' in the console, but too many tests shows, I only want to show failed test. How should I do.

Comment: Nothing helpful [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalatest-users/Ht-5Z4JXjHQ)?

Answer (score 3):

you can run sbt testQuick.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html

also if you use ScalaTest you can add:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-cG")
```

to your 'build.sbt'.

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner

Answer (score 1):

According to the recent https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner …

```
sbt> test -- -oI
```

> -o[…] select the standard output reporter
> …
> I - show reminder of failed and canceled tests without stack traces
> T - show reminder of failed and canceled tests with short stack traces
> G - show reminder of failed and canceled tests with full stack traces